# Data not displayed in Influx DB

Tags: jmeter, influxdb

I am running a JMeter script for 50 users and for 5 minutes. And I have configured the InfluxDB and Backend listener as shown below:

But when I am checking for data in the influxDB in the table - test1, I am not getting records for the different samplers in the test plan.

All I am getting is records with transaction id as - 'all' and 'internal'

[image: Test Plan - Sampler Request]

[image: Backend Listener Configuration]
[image: InfuxDB Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least an issue, change in percentiles the separator from "," to ";"

This is fixed in nightly build if you'd like to test it:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Comment: It's wired! JMeter with the same version (3.3 r1808647) works properly for me; even when I use "," instead of ";" in the percentiles property.

Comment: regarding separator, what happens is that the values are ignored, no impact if you don’t customize(50,80,90 would be ignored for example). What was your problem ?

Comment: @UBIK LOAD PACK - The change in separator from "," to ";" has worked for me and now I am getting data in influxDB...Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks for your feedback and accepting answer, you're welcome :-)